# Receiving the correct array from the api, but the values ​do not appear in the mat table

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I decided to learn angular a few weeks ago, but I have difficulties. I can't populate a table with values ​​received from an API using MatTable    .
I am receiving the correct values ​​from the api but these values ​​do not appear in the table, no errors while compiling.
I've tried many solutions but none of them worked. Please help

```
HTML:
```

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="ID">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ID </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.ID}} </td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="animaltype">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> AnimalType </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.animaltype}} </td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="race">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Race </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.race}} </td>
  </ng-container>
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

Typescript:

```
    import { AfterViewInit, Component, ViewChild, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
    import { User } from 'src/app/models/user.model';
    import { Adoption } from 'src/app/models/adoption.model';
    import { AccountService } from '../services/account.service';

    @Component({
    selector: 'app-myadoptions',
    templateUrl: './myadoptions.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./myadoptions.component.css']
    })

     export class MyadoptionsComponent implements OnInit {
      allAdoption: Adoption[];
      dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Adoption>;
      displayedColumns: string[] = ['ID', 'name', 'animaltype', 'race'];
      user: User;
      string: string;
      payload;

      constructor(private accountService: AccountService) {
      }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.adoptions();
      }

      public adoptions() {
      let resp = this.accountService.getAdoptions(this.getUserId());
      resp.subscribe(data => {
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data);
        console.log(this.dataSource.data);
      });
      }

      getUserId() {
        this.string = localStorage.getItem('user');
        this.user = (JSON.parse(this.string));
           if (this.user.token) {
            this.payload = this.user.token.split(".")[1];
            this.payload = window.atob(this.payload);
            const userString = JSON.parse(this.payload);
            return parseInt(userString.UserID);
      }
     }

     }
```

Model:

```
    export class Adoption {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    animaltype: string;
    race: string;
    UserID: number; 
    text: string;
    adopted: boolean; 
     }
```

Console log:
[Console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYv4G.png)

Table:
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEyw7.png)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the response from `getAdoptions` has the data you are looking for in a nested property named `data`, but what you are loading into the MatTable is the outer response object itself.

i.e., you are doing:

```
let resp = this.accountService.getAdoptions(this.getUserId());
      resp.subscribe(data => {
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data);
```

which looks reasonable, but when I look at your console output for `this.dataSource.data`, I see that the Adoption records are in a property named `data`. i.e., the original shape of the returned information is probably:

```
getAdoptionsResponse: {
  data: Adoption[];
}
```

If this is the case, you need to update your code to do:

```
let resp = this.accountService.getAdoptions(this.getUserId());
      resp.subscribe(response => {
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(response.data);
```

in order to load the data correctly.

You should be able to verify this (or refute it) by printing out the value you get from the getAdoptions subscription.

Comment: I tried but it didnt work ... Thanks anyway :)